Twilio function returns error with media included
We've been using Twilio as a broadcast service for different SMS groups that our company has. For instance, a end user would text "Subscribe" to XXX-XXX-XXXX and then be signed up to receive messages.
We had been able to send media like photos in the message but sometime last week something changed. Twilio will receive the media, but when it goes to send the media to everyone that is subscribed to the broadcast group, it returns an 11200 error. Upon deeper looking it's returning a 401 error when it tries to get the media file.
We're using several different functions that are built on Twilio and I'm wondering if I need to update the function to handle retrieving the media url(s).
Below is what our function looks like.
const helpMessage =
  'Hello! Text "subscribe" to receive updates, "stop" to stop getting messages, and "start" to receive them again.';
const subscribeSuccessMessage = 'Thanks! You have been subscribed for updates.';
const subscribeFailMessage =
  "Dang it. We couldn't subscribe you - try again later?";
const broadcastNotAuthorizedMessage =
  'Your phone number is not authorized to broadcast in this application';
const broadcastSuccessMessage = 'Boom! Message broadcast to all subscribers.';
const broadcastFailMessage =
  'Well this is awkward. Your message failed to send, try again later.';

// Helper class for commands
class Command {
  // Create a new instance with necessary arguments from the incoming SMS
  constructor(event, context) {
    this.fromNumber = event.From;
    this.body = event.Body || '';
    this.mediaURL = event.mediaURL || '';
    this.event = event;
    this.context = context;

    const client = this.context.getTwilioClient();
    this.notify = client.notify.services(
      process.env.BROADCAST_NOTIFY_SERVICE_SID
    );

    /*
     * Occassionally, US numbers will be passed without the preceding
     * country code - check for this eventuality and fix it
     */
    if (this.fromNumber.indexOf('+') !== 0) {
      this.fromNumber = `+1${this.fromNumber}`;
    }
  }

  // Get an array of arguments after the first word for a command
  get commandArguments() {
    return this.body.trim().split(' ').slice(1);
  }

  // Get the full text after the command with spaces reinserted
  get commandText() {
    return this.commandArguments.join(' ');
  }

  // Execute command async (to be overridden by subclasses)
  run(callback) {
    callback(null, 'Command not implemented.');
  }
}

/* Subclasses for supported commands */

class HelpCommand extends Command {
  run(callback) {
    callback(null, helpMessage);
  }
}

class SubscribeCommand extends Command {
  run(callback) {
    // Create a new SMS Notify binding for this user's phone number
    this.notify.bindings
      .create({
        identity: this.fromNumber,
        bindingType: 'sms',
        address: this.fromNumber,
      })
      .then(() => {
        callback(null, subscribeSuccessMessage);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        callback(err, subscribeFailMessage);
      });
  }
}

class BroadcastCommand extends Command {
  constructor(event, context) {
    super(event, context);
    this.adminNumbers = context.BROADCAST_ADMIN_NUMBERS;
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
  run(callback) {
    /*
     * Check if sender is in list of admins, stored in the system environment
     * as a comma-separated string
     */
    if (this.adminNumbers.indexOf(this.fromNumber) < 0) {
      return callback(null, broadcastNotAuthorizedMessage);
    }

    // Create a new Notification for all bindings with the text of the message
    this.notify.notifications
      .create({
        tag: 'all',
        body: this.commandText,
        mediaURL: this.mediaURL,
      })
      .then(() => {
        callback(null, broadcastSuccessMessage);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        callback(err, broadcastFailMessage);
      });
  }
}

class MediaCommand extends Command{
  constructor(event, context){
    super(event, context);
    this.adminNumbers = context.BROADCAST_ADMIN_NUMBERS;
  }

  run(callback){
    if(this.adminNumbers.indexOf(this.fromNumber) < 0) {
      return callback(null, broadcastNotAuthorizedMessage);
    }

    console.log(this.event.Body);
    
    this.notify.notifications
      .create({
        tag: 'all',
        body: this.event.Body,
        sms: {media_urls: [this.event.MediaUrl0]},
      })
      .then(() => {
        callback(null, broadcastSuccessMessage);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
          callback(err, broadcastFailMessage);
      });
  }

}

// Handle incoming SMS commands
exports.handler = (context, event, callback) => {
  // Get command text from incoming SMS body
  let cmd = event.Body || '';
  console.log(event.NumMedia);
  if(event.NumMedia != 0){
    cmd = 'media';
  } else {
    cmd = cmd.trim().split(' ')[0].toLowerCase();
  }
  // Choose other commands as appropriate
  const CommandClasses = {
    subscribe: SubscribeCommand,
    broadcast: BroadcastCommand,
    media: MediaCommand,
  };
  const CommandClass = CommandClasses[cmd] || HelpCommand;
  const cmdInstance = new CommandClass(event, context);

  // Execute command
  cmdInstance.run((_err, message) => {
    const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
    twiml.message(message);
    callback(null, twiml);
  });
};

